# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at test$2$1.actionPerformed(test.java:230)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source
```

from this code:

```
Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Integer.parseInt(tb_port[i].getText()));
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Which is line 230?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah infortunitelly, it's the one before the word 'next'

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` has nothing to do with RMI. Neither does 880 yards of Swing code. You really need to learn to read a stack trace, and how to distinguish relevance from irrelevance

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

and

```
tp_port[i]
```

`i` is 3, and `tp_port[]` only has 3 or fewer elements.

Comment: @shinjw Lest the OP and future readers be confused, there is no guessing here whatsoever. It follows directly from the exception. If the OP hadn't posted half a mile of 99% irrelevant code I might have delved further into the underlying cause.

Comment: Totally misphrased that. Did not mean to use the word `guess`. OP made an insightful question. And you provided clear and concise answer.